# Remove duplicates csv based on first value keeping the longest line between duplicates

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting, perl, csv

I have many different csv files in a folder (megadrive.txt, snes.txt) like this:

```
Aerial Assault (USA);Aerial Assault (USA);Sega Master System;;;;;;;;;0;;;;;
Aerial Assault (USA);Aerial Assault (USA);Sega Master System;;1990;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
After Burner (World);After Burner (World);Sega Master System;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
After Burner (World);After Burner (World);Sega Master System;;1988;Sega;Flying;;;;;0;;;;;
Air Rescue (Europe);Air Rescue (Europe);Sega Master System;;1992;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
Aladdin (Europe);Aladdin (Europe);Sega Master System;;1994;Sega;Platform;;;;;0;;;;;
```

In these CSVs, I have many, many lines and many have the same first field.
I want to batch-process these files and, in each file, only keep the longest line for each first field. For example, the output should be:

```
Aerial Assault (USA);Aerial Assault (USA);Sega Master System;;1990;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
After Burner (World);After Burner (World);Sega Master System;;1988;Sega;Flying;;;;;0;;;;;
Air Rescue (Europe);Air Rescue (Europe);Sega Master System;;1992;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
Aladdin (Europe);Aladdin (Europe);Sega Master System;;1994;Sega;Platform;;;;;0;;;;;
```

In particular

```
Aerial Assault (USA);Aerial Assault (USA);Sega Master System;;;;;;;;;0;;;;;
Aerial Assault (USA);Aerial Assault (USA);Sega Master System;;1990;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
```

both records have the first field duplicated but the second entry is longer, so I would like to keep the second entry end remove all the shorter lines with the same first field.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your fields are defined by `;`. And that there can be no `;` inside a field. If those assumptions are true, you can do:

```
$ awk -F';' '{if(!a[$1]||length($0)>length(a[$1])){a[$1]=$0}}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' file.txt
Aerial Assault (USA);Aerial Assault (USA);Sega Master System;;1990;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
After Burner (World);After Burner (World);Sega Master System;;1988;Sega;Flying;;;;;0;;;;;
Aladdin (Europe);Aladdin (Europe);Sega Master System;;1994;Sega;Platform;;;;;0;;;;;
Air Rescue (Europe);Air Rescue (Europe);Sega Master System;;1992;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
```

However, this has the drawback of needing to store one line per 1st field in memory and that might be an issue for huge files. If so, you can try this instead:

```
$ awk '{print length($0)";"$0}' file.txt | sort -t';' -rnk1,1 | awk -F';' '++a[$2]==1' | cut -d';' -f2-
Aerial Assault (USA);Aerial Assault (USA);Sega Master System;;;;;;;;;0;;;;;
After Burner (World);After Burner (World);Sega Master System;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
Air Rescue (Europe);Air Rescue (Europe);Sega Master System;;1992;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
Aladdin (Europe);Aladdin (Europe);Sega Master System;;1994;Sega;Platform;;;;;0;;;;;
```

You can apply either solution to all of your files with a simple shell loop:

```
for f in *txt; do 
    awk -F';' '{if(!a[$1]||length($0)>length(a[$1])){a[$1]=$0}}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' "$f" > "$f".fixed
done
```

Or

```
for f in *txt; do 
    awk '{print length($0)";"$0}' file.txt | sort -t';' -rnk1,1 | 
        awk -F';' '++a[$2]==1' | cut -d';' -f2- > "$f".fixed
done
```

Comment: @EdMorton absolutely right about the sort, thanks.Should be fixed now. As for tabs, though, what if the 2nd field had a tab? And sure, `!++seen[$2]++` might be more idiomatic, but it's also more cryptic to those not familiar with the idiom, so I don't see any benefit in using it here. I've done so often enough in other cases.

Comment: Good point about the possibility of the 2nd field containing a tab, I hadn't considered that. wrt the idiom - IMHO idioms are good for everyone to become familiar with if they're going to be using a tool/language so if we use one and someone isn't familiar with it and investigates or asks then it's still a win.

Comment: I deleted my answer and upvoted yours since they're now both so similar. Talking of cryptic though `{if(!a[$1]||length($0)>length(a[$1])){a[$1]=$0}}END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}` could stand a few newlines and indenting and maybe a temp var or 2 :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sort(1)`:

```
sort -rt';' filename | sort -t';' -usk1,1

Aerial Assault (USA);Aerial Assault (USA);Sega Master System;;1990;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
After Burner (World);After Burner (World);Sega Master System;;1988;Sega;Flying;;;;;0;;;;;
Air Rescue (Europe);Air Rescue (Europe);Sega Master System;;1992;Sega;Shooter;;;;;0;;;;;
Aladdin (Europe);Aladdin (Europe);Sega Master System;;1994;Sega;Platform;;;;;0;;;;;
```

Both sorts will use the `;` as the field delimiter (`-t';'`). The first will reverse sort (`-r`), so that the empty fields come *after* the non-empty fields, and the second sort will sort by the first field (`-k1,1`), and remove extra lines with the same first field (`-u` = uniq), but will otherwise keep to order set by the first sort (`-s` = stable).

This assumes that instead of the "longest" line as the title says, you actually want the "most complete", ie. between two lines with the same first field, the shorter one has always a *subset* of the fields of the longer one (which is the only case where discarding the shorter lines can make any sense IMHO). It also assumes that your sort implementation has a `-s` (stable) option: both the GNU (Linux) and BSD sort do.

If you want to do it on a batch of files, you should use `find`:

```
find dir -type f -name '*.txt' \
    -exec sh -c 'for f; do sort -rt";" "$f" |
    sort -t";" -usk1,1 > "$f.new" && echo mv "$f.new" "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

Adjust the find's predicates (`-name`, etc) and only remove the `echo` from before `mv` if you're ready to clobber your existing files.

Comment: That won't keep the longest lines since `sort -rt';'` would output `foo;z;` before `foo;bar;lots;of;extras`.

Comment: I was kind of second guessing the OP, my bad, I have clarified the answer. If the challenge really is to sort by first field then by length, then preprocessing the input to prepend the length is probably the way to go, something like `awk '{print length";"$0}'  file | sort -t';' -k2,2 -k1,1rn | sed 's/[^;]*;//' | sort -st';' -k1,1 -u`